# How to access local Windows files in bash with Windows 10 Developer Mode?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, command-line, bash

I have enabled the Ubuntu bash command line feature that comes with Windows Developer Mode.

I cannot seem to be able to access any directories outside of a linux looking filesystem (ex. / has bin, usr, etc...) and cd / leaves me at that root folder. Perhaps there's a sandbox being used here.

How do I access local windows files, say in my Downloads or Desktop directory and use them with the Developer command line?

Comment: It's much easier to do this on 1703 provided you upgrade your WSL instance to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04

Comment: How do I upgrade that?

Comment: Simple way, reset the WSL instance, after you upgrade.  In-place command is documented.

Comment: Duplicate of your comment question: https://superuser.com/questions/1103675/update-linux-subsystem-on-windows-ubuntu-to-16-04/1132327#1132327

Comment: look at the [where is the linux filesystem located in windows 10? question](https://superuser.com/questions/1067373/where-is-the-linux-subsystems-filesystem-located-in-windows-10)