# Installed Ubuntu Linux on Windows; cannot upgrade to latest LTS version

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, upgrade

I installed Ubuntu Linux on Windows 10. Everything seems to be working fine. The version I installed has no version number, and from the command line the kernel version is:

```
$ uname -r
4.4.0-17763-Microsoft
```

This would correspond to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. On Microsoft Store is written:

> To upgrade to a new release please run do-release-upgrade in the Ubuntu terminal.

This is what I get:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
[sudo] password for user:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
```

The available Ubuntu releases up to today are 19.04, 18.10, 18.04 LTS, 17.10, 17.04 and 16.10.

This is what is in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`:
`Prompt=lts`

Shouldn't the system upgrade to version 18.04 LTS?

---

Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, version 10.0.17763, 64 bit

Comment: Yes, yes it should. Please run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` then try again the release upgrade.

Comment: Let's start with some required information.  What version of Windows 10 are you running?  Instead of commenting be sure you edit your question and include this vital information.

Comment: Did you install WSL Ubuntu through the Windows Store or using the legacy method? [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1103675/update-linux-subsystem-on-windows-ubuntu-to-16-04) might also help

Comment: @Ramhound - I installed it through the Windows Store.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - Done. Now it says: "There is no development version of an LTS available.". The kernel version is unchanged.

Comment: Really weird. Well, try some suggestions in the link above.